# Twitter and Facebook time difference by one hour for post before 13 Mar

Tags: facebook, twitter

This is simple enough question. I know **daylight saving time** but I am living in **non-DST** place and still confused. I have a few posts, posted before **13 Mar** via TweetDeck which post to Twitter and Facebook at the same time. Now, viewing the posts the Twitter and Facebook times are different by one hour. Facebook is one hour earlier Twitter. Either Facebook or Twitter are not handling **DST** properly. It is hard to search for this since both names are used in almost modern web sites. Why is no one from non-DST place blogging about this?!

After calculating for several hours my confidence level is still in between because I don't know which is using local time or UTC on their server, which is calculated +7hr/+8hr manually or automatically to get UTC time. I still don't know which may use standard time instead of **DST** enabled on the server. There are so many possibilities unless there is any Facebook or Twitter developer here that can explain their server time settings and how they calculate to display the time.

This is one of the example:

http://www.facebook.com/callmelann/posts/10150102797126597
http://twitter.com/CallMeLaNN/status/37892755611066368

Which one is right?

Comment: anyone from non-DST place realize this?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is? Your Facebook post has a time of 15:09 and your Tweet has a time of 15:15

Comment: because your place conserve DST. You can see the different if you located on non-DST enabled. or try to change timezone and turn off DST in your system time?

Comment: Sorry not your system time but like twitter it detact based on IP location. you able to see it if you use web proxy where it not observe DST.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check your settings on both services to make sure you have chosen the correct time-zone.  If you're in a country that doesn't observe DST, make sure you select the correct time-zone or un-tick the box to adjust for DST.  I honestly don't use Facebook or Twitter (I'm a bit of a paranoid security geek), but I do know that Facebook won't let you change your time-zone after your account is set ([Facebook Help Centre](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=17276)). And Twitter, on the flip-side does "hours ago..." rather than a specific date/time. There might be an account-setting that adjusts that to your local time-zone, but that's up to you to look for.

Comment: I think not really. This is not in my case. If I logged out or other people see the time here get the same result, still different by 1 hour. Also not only my specific tweet, other people tweet here also the same.